# Why does conda show two different sets of channels?

Tags: conda

When I do `conda env export` I see four channels (shown below), but when I tried to delete one I got an error saying the channel was not in the config file. Why are channels listed in my channels if they are not really channels and how do I get rid of them?

```
(base) C:\Users\User>conda env export
name: base
channels:
  - pytorch
  - anaconda
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:

(base) C:\Users\User>conda config --remove channels pytorch

CondaKeyError: 'channels': 'pytorch' is not in the 'channels' key of the config file


(base) C:\Users\User>conda config --show channels
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `conda env export` command looks for where the installed packages are sourced from. Your **base** environment has one or more packages installed from the `pytorch` channel. You would have to reinstall the packages from a different channel to get rid of it in the export.